# Get paths from directed graph structure using MongoDB

Tags: python, node.js, database, mongodb, graph

**Background**

I have a mongodb database with documents containing a title and a list of titles of other documents it has connections to. That list of other titles contains titles which do not (yet) exist in the database. For some kind of a recommendation and finding equalities I need to know how "far" two documents are from each other and especially how I can get from one to another document.

Ideally I'd like to have a solution for which I don't need to know the whole database in my program which would make this problem kind of trivial.

[image]

**What I tried**

I tried using `$graphLookup` in aggregation but I feel like it will not be able to provide me with a generic solution top this. Using $graphLookup I was able to get Element A and all its connected Elements (B, D) "populated", but the result was very rough and looked very brute-forcish.

**Expected result**

I would like to know all possible paths (maybe with a max-depth) from one element to another.

Based on the image above, for query `"A -> B"` I'd like to get a list of `"A, D, B"` and `"A, B"`.

For `"A -> G"` I'd like to get `"A, B, F, G"`, `"A, B, G"` and `"A, D, B, G"`.

Sadly, I do have a lot of elements (thousands). Is there some smart query I can use to maybe get the exact result using a query only? Or atleast some smart filter query to get only a subset of all relevant documents which I can then combine with graph theory in python or node.js?